# PostgreSQL Filter Incomplete Year

Tags: postgresql

PROBLEM: In records below some months are missing. Need to filter out whole years with incomplete months.

```
DATE             VALUE
2018-01-01       123
2018-02-01       123
2018-03-01       123
2018-04-01       123
2018-05-01       123
2018-06-01       123
2018-07-01       123
2018-08-01       123
2018-09-01       123
2018-10-01       123
2018-11-01       123
2018-12-01       123
2019-01-01       123 // Remove.
```

RESEARCH:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE ...
```

QUESTION:

```
How to get:

DATE             VALUE
2018-01-01       123
2018-02-01       123
2018-03-01       123
2018-04-01       123
2018-05-01       123
2018-06-01       123
2018-07-01       123
2018-08-01       123
2018-09-01       123
2018-10-01       123
2018-11-01       123
2018-12-01       123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a group by statement to find those where all months are present:

```
select to_char(date, 'yyyy')
from the_table
group by to_char(date, 'yyyy')
having count(distinct to_char(date, 'mm')) = 12;
```

This can be used to get only those you are interested in:

```
select *
from the_table
where to_char(date, 'yyyy') in (select to_char(date, 'yyyy')
                                   from the_table
                                   group by to_char(date, 'yyyy')
                                   having count(distinct to_char(date, 'mm')) = 12);
```

Alternatively use `extract(year from ..)`

```
select extract(year from date)
from the_table
group by extract(year from date)
having count(*) = 12;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/LKF6618

Comment: If there can be more than one value per month (test data and text don't say) then `count(*) = 12` should be changed into `count(distinct to_char(date,'mm')) = 12`

Comment: If you think my point is good, you should replace the two `count(distinct to_char(date, 'yyyy'))` with `count(distinct to_char(date, 'mm'))` in your answer ;-)